# scala spray get long list of parameters

Tags: scala, spray

I have an application written on scala/spray, and a GET function that need to receive a long list of parameters (30+).

what is the best way to receive them in route as an hashMap or object?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use [parameterMap](http://spray.io/documentation/1.1.2/spray-routing/parameter-directives/parameterMap/)

example:

```
parameterMap { params =>
    def paramString(param: (String, String)): String = s"""${param._1} = '${param._2}'"""
    complete(s"The parameters are ${params.map(paramString).mkString(", ")}")
  }
```